# Cypress - Trying to access/use dropdown with no id

Tags: cypress

I'm trying to set a telephone numbers country code in Cypress. If I had an 'id' to work with I would just use something like

```
cy.get('#countryCode').select('+44')
```

However the code I'm working with doesn't have an id to work with. The dropdown html looks like

```
<select _ngcontent-kln-c8="" aria-label="Country Code for home phone number" class="uppercase mat-input-element mat-form-field-autofill-control cdk-text-field-autofill-monitored ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched" matnativecontrol="" id="mat-input-6" aria-describedby="mat-hint-3" aria-invalid="false" aria-required="false"><option _ngcontent-kln-c8="" style="display: none" value="">+null</option><!----><option _ngcontent-kln-c8="" class="uppercase ng-star-inserted" value="1: 44"> +44 (United Kingdom) </option><option _ngcontent-kln-c8="" class="uppercase ng-star-inserted" value="2: 353"> +353 (Ireland) </option>
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not a problem at all. Based on the HTML snippet you provided, I would recommend using the `aria-label` since this should be unique on the page.

`cy.get('[aria-label="Country Code for home phone number"]').select(''+44')`

Let me know if you have any other questions!

Comment: Hello, thank you very much for your help. It's working perfectly now.